# i don't understand what is %[^\n]

Tags: c

I saw a program to input a string without using %s, %c format specifiers and gets, fgets functions even. Can explain each and every line of this code? s1 is character pointer. But pointer takes address. What is this ""\45\133\136\12\135\163". We have another character pointer *s2 ok. Now scanf takes two addresses i understood this but without % specifier. How? And then this printf(s2) statement.

I read ANSI C book by K&R but it wasn't there. Bible of C doesn't have this concept. How come? Please tell me where to read more about %[^\n]. Where else i can use this concept.

```
int main()
{
char *s1 = "\45\133\136\12\135\163", *s2;
printf("Enter the string: "); 
scanf(s1,s2);
printf(s2);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing about `%[^\n]` in the code sample. Please focus your question-- it's too broad as is.

Comment: Why are you specifying the format string as escape codes instead of a readable format?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure But there is!!

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: `s1` *is* `"%[^\n]s"`, only using escape codes.

Comment: This is not my code i read it somewhere and totally got confused so i asked here i hope you guys can explain me everything about it.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf explains a bit about scanf and format strings.

Comment: @interjay That's, like, the whole point of the question :)

Comment: Why are people down voting this question ? Its an intresting question

Comment: This question is unclear due to the obfuscation. Now that it is clear what's going on, I would consider it too localized (because seriously, when is the next time you will run into `%[^\n]` in *obfuscated form*?). This is simply not likely to be useful to others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is merely obfuscated and is exactly equivalent to:

```
int main()
{
  char *s1 = "%[^\n]s", *s2;
  printf("Enter the string: "); 
  scanf(s1, s2);
  printf(s2);
  return 0;
}
```

The obfuscated string literal `"\45\133\136\12\135\163"` is using octal character representation. For example, `'\12'` is character code 10, LF, same as `'\n'`.

Let's decode the format string:

- `%` - introduces a conversion
- `[` - starts a match of a nonempty sequence of characters from the specified set
- `^` - indicates that the following characters are to be *excluded* from the set
- `\n` - the set *excludes* the newline (character code 10)
- `]` - ends the set specification *and the conversion*.
- `s` - matches a literal `s`.

Thus, the `scanf` will input any non-empty string that doesn't contain a newline, as long as it's followed by `s`.  The `s` is essentially unnecessary and likely a bug.

### BUGS

It should be noted that the code has **three** (or most likely four) bugs and won't work as shown. Someone should be focusing on obfuscating correct code to start with.

1. `scanf` reads into a buffer pointed-to by an uninitialized pointer. If it works, it's by pure chance. It should be reading into an allocated buffer instead.
2. The use of a string conversion in `scanf` **without the length** is also a bug.
3. The `s` at the end of the format string is likely invalid, unless the intent was to match a literal `s` at the end of the string. It is a bug in the light of:

   - It being invalid (if allowed) to specify infinite length string conversions.
   - It maching if the string conversion matches full length.
4. `printf(s2)`, where `s2` is entered by the user, **is a bug too**.

I must stress that #2 and #4 are not a "security hole" or any such thing, just bugs plain and simple. If any textbook shows such code, the authors should be dragged over hot coals. **I mean it**. It will work sometimes, some other times it will crash, yet another time it will format your hard drive.

The code should read something like:

```
int main()
{
  char *s1 = "%255[^\n]";
  char s2[256];
  printf("Enter the string: "); 
  scanf(s1, s2);
  printf("%s\n", s2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error number one is related but not the described one: Reading of an uninitialized memory-less automatic-storage variable results in UB.

Comment: Also, the final `s` is harmless, and thus not actually a bug (a bug potentially has at least some effect).

Comment: @Deduplicator First, we note that it is always a bug (a buffer overflow waiting to happen) not to have a finite string conversion length given. In the case above, I've set it to 255. So, with the `s` present, a string consisting of 255 non-newline characters, followed by an `s` as the 256th character, will match, and the `s` will be consumed. That's likely not what was intended. C's format-string-based I/O is tricky and it's very, very easy to mess it up. It's has a bad reputation for a reason, and we have C++ for a good reason :)

Comment: Ehm, ... Where am I arguing against reading without bound into a finite buffer not always being a bug? I'm saying the `s` could not be matched (as the input was either closed or contains a newline next), and thus had no effect *in the original*. Of course correcting the infinite store to finite buffer problem means other adjustments need to be made too. Also, I really would not hold C++ IO up as a better model - though a printf-style variadic-template function could be - as it's atrocious for internationalization. Anyway, what about my first comment, which you didn't handle yet?

Comment: @Deduplicator I think I'm saying what you're saying: there's use of an uninitialized pointer: "scanf reads into a buffer pointed-to by an uninitialized pointer". That the pointer is an automatic storage variable is obvious. Better yet: say how *you* would want to say that, and indicate how what I said means something else than what you intended to say :)

Comment: @Deduplicator "thus had no effect in the original" I think that we all know by now that the original has no chance at working, we must merely fix it step-by-step, each time recognizing what's wrong. It's, I think, fairly obvious that the `s` at the end of the original's format string was there for wrong reasons. The "harmlessness" of it was IMHO immaterial, since the argument would go "yeah you have a buffer overflow, but when you do, the final `s` in the format string is OK". It sends a wrong message. Remember: this is a noob question. Everything wrong with the code must be exposed.

Comment: @Deduplicator Essentially, once you fix the code, leaving the `s` in would be a bug. So it can't be left in. So it was a latent bug since the get go. Nasty one, too. I can't but imagine someone chasing down the repro case with `s` at position 256... Latent bug since it would be exposed by fixes to other bugs...

Comment: Regarding the `s`: I might have been a tad to nit-picky and language-lawyerly there, though adding why it did not have any effect when testing would be a good thing. Regarding the other one: The bug is reading an uninitialized memory-less auto-variable at all, irrespective what shall happen with the read value. Writing through it as if it pointed to a valid buffer of sufficient (read: infinite) length is a follow-on error.